# Why is it false that for all $y\in\mathbb{R^n}$ the solution of the initial value problem $x(0) = y$ exists for all time $t$.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, initial-value-problems

Is the following statement false because our solutions for the initial value problem may not exist when $t=0$; depending on our function? Also, uniqueness does not exist if the system is nonlinear, such as quadratic. Hence, the statement below is false.

Statement: Consider $x'=f(x)$ and suppose that for every initial condition $x(0)=x_0$ solutions exists and are unique for some time interval $[-a(x_0), a(x_0)]$ whose length depends on the initial value $x_0$. Then for all $y\in\mathbb{R^n}$ the solution of the initial value problem $x(0) = y$ exists for all time $t$.

Comment: There are so many misunderstandings in your post that it would be difficult to try to reply to anything. Please be specific about what you intend to ask. For example: what is your notion of solution? why should the sentence "Consider..." be related to the last sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counter-example: 
$$ f(x) = \sec^2(\arctan(x)) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
This function $f$ is smooth and so existence/uniqueness applies for the ODE $x'(t) = f(x(t))$.

However, for any $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ we observe that 
$$ x(t) = \tan(t + \arctan(x_0)) $$ 
is the unique solution to $x'(t) = f(x(t))$ for the initial condition $x(0)=x_0$. 
 This solution is only defined on a **portion** of the timeline: It blows up to infinity in finite time.

Comment: Thank you for the help, so the statement holds true then. Interesting. I was a bit confused at first

Comment: I do not know what statement you are referring to.  If you mean the statement you wrote in your question, then, my counter-example above shows that statement is false.  The solution of the initial value problem exists and is unique, but  only locally.  All solutions blow up to infinity in finite time, they do not exist on the entire timeline.

Comment: Yes, I meant by the statement i wrote in my post. Sorry for the confusion and thank you again for the explanation!